# Why does timedelta calculation across Daylight Saving Time differ when using dateutil.tz or timezone object in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, dst

I am learning the timezone and Daylight Saving Time in python. When I calculate the time difference around Daylight Saving time using two methods, they are supposed to give the same time difference, however, they give different results.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
from dateutil import tz
```

1. First method using dateutil.tz

```py
eastern = tz.gettz('America/New_York')
t1 = datetime(2017, 3, 12, 1, 59, 59, tzinfo=eastern)
t2 = datetime(2017, 3, 12, 3, 0, 0, tzinfo=eastern)
print(t1.isoformat())
print(t2.isoformat())
print((t2-t1).seconds)
```

The outputs are:

2017-03-12T01:59:59-05:00

2017-03-12T03:00:00-04:00

3601

2. Second method setting the timezones manually

```py
EST = timezone(timedelta(hours=-5))
EDT = timezone(timedelta(hours=-4))
spring_ahead_159am = datetime(2017, 3, 12, 1, 59, 59, tzinfo = EST)
spring_ahead_3am = datetime(2017, 3, 12, 3, 0, 0, tzinfo = EDT)

print(spring_ahead_159am.isoformat())
print(spring_ahead_3am.isoformat())
print((spring_ahead_3am - spring_ahead_159am).seconds)
```

The outputs are:

2017-03-12T01:59:59-05:00

2017-03-12T03:00:00-04:00

1

As you can see t1 is equal to spring_ahead_159am, and t2 is equal to spring_ahead_3am. So how come (t2 - t1 ) != (spring_ahead_3am - spring_ahead_159am)?

I compared them and they are equal:

```py
print(t1 == spring_ahead_159am)
print(t2 == spring_ahead_3am )
```

The outputs are:

True

True

Comment: it's a feature, not a bug, see [Semantics of timezone-aware datetime arithmetic](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/02/aware-datetime-arithmetic.html) + my comment on [your issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/105254#issuecomment-1575514088).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be unintended behavior due to the implementation of the `__sub__()` method of `datetime` ([link to github](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e01b04c9075c6468ed57bc883693ec2a06a6dd8e/Lib/_pydatetime.py#L2247)). When you subtract two datetime objects, it checks if the time zones are the same object.

```
if self._tzinfo is other._tzinfo:
    return base
```

Since the tz objects passed into `t1` and `t2` from `dateutil` is the same object, the `datetime` object assumes the timezone stays the same and does not take into account daylight savings.

This seems to be a bug and you should definitely open a [github issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues) about it.

Comment: I think this would be the true cause. Nice and quick answer. I already opened a github issue about it.

Comment: Agree with this answer.  Note that `spring_ahead_3am - t1` and `t2 - spring_ahead_159am` both give the right value.